# Facebook likes - email or other kind or report possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So it seems the option to get email when somebody likes my post is gone already. Do you think there is a possibility to enable it somehow? Or I am thinking if there would be a way to export/download the notifications so then I could parse it by some script or just filter in a text editor? If I say it simple I would like to have a way to filter out people who have zero activity on my timeline - no likes, no comments. After I find them I will write them some nice message and then unfriend. I just don't want to be unfair you know.

Comment: I'm surprised by what you intend. Have you confirmed that people with zero likes or comments really aren't reading your posts? Many people look at my FB posts but don't like them or comment. When I talk to them in person, I find out that they have seen things. Several of my friends do this.

Comment: Yes that is possible, but really - if they never have that one second to click like then how am I supposed to know that they read something? I intend to send them a little questionnaire with one of the answers being "oh I am sorry, I read your posts, but I just never click on anything" :) I know that some people do that like this from whatever reasons. Just want to know why and who... sort of a research.

Comment: well... seems like 50 reputation is not enough to get an answer :-\